# Subspaces of dimension $n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $A$ be the set of all vectors of the form $(e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n)$, where $ e_i\in\{0,1\}$ and the base field is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So $|A|=2^n$. Let $B\subseteq A$ be such that the all-zero vector is not in $B$, and any subspace of $A$ of dimension $n-1$ has an element in $B$. What is the maximum value $d$ such that $B$ always contains a subspace of dimension $d$ except the zero vector?

To start off, there are $2^n-1$ subspaces of dimension $n-1$, because we can instead choose the orthogonal subspace of dimension $1$, which is equivalent to choosing a nonzero vector.